# How to get the data from the feed of blogspot?

Tags: html, xml, blogger

I want to to get the post feed to put on an HTML page...
To get the posts I'm using the following link:
'https://www.blogger.com/feeds/bloggerID/posts/default?max-results=N'
where `bloggerID` is the blogger id and the `N` is the number of posts.
When I put the link on the browser I get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><?xml-stylesheet href="https://www.blogger.com/styles/atom.css" type="text/css"?><feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss' xmlns:thr='http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0' xmlns:blogger='http://schemas.google.com/blogger/2008'><id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-614640065733671379</id><updated>2019-12-08T16:30:37.161-08:00</updated><title type='text'>Angélica Abadia Paulista Ribeiro</title><subtitle type='html'></subtitle><link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default?max-results=3'/><link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default?max-results=3'/><link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default'/><link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/'/><link rel='hub' href='http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/'/><author><name>AngelRibeiro</name><email>noreply@blogger.com</email><gd:image rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail' width='18' height='32' src='//4.bp.blogspot.com/-HCajnihNU-o/Uzoge8-ME2I/AAAAAAAABdo/x_XEG0duaZQ/s32/*'/></author><generator version='7.00' uri='https://www.blogger.com'>Blogger</generator><openSearch:totalResults>3</openSearch:totalResults><openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex><openSearch:itemsPerPage>3</openSearch:itemsPerPage><entry><id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-614640065733671379.post-3449800807582452116</id><published>2019-11-27T09:43:00.003-08:00</published><updated>2019-12-08T16:28:04.059-08:00</updated><title type='text'>teste3</title><content type='html'>&lt;div style="background-color: white; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: inherit; margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;"&gt;&lt;div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"&gt;&lt;a href="https://www.surveycto.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ai-and-dev.jpg" imageanchor="1" style="clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"&gt;&lt;img border="0" data-original-height="449" data-original-width="800" height="179" src="https://www.surveycto.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/ai-and-dev.jpg" width="320" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/div&gt;asdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfaasdfasdfasdfasdfa&lt;/div&gt;</content><link rel='replies' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/feeds/3449800807582452116/comments/default' title='Postar comentários'/><link rel='replies' type='text/html' href='https://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/2019/11/teste3.html#comment-form' title='0 Comentários'/><link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default/3449800807582452116'/><link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default/3449800807582452116'/><link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/2019/11/teste3.html' title='teste3'/><author><name>AngelRibeiro</name><email>noreply@blogger.com</email><gd:image rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail' width='18' height='32' src='//4.bp.blogspot.com/-HCajnihNU-o/Uzoge8-ME2I/AAAAAAAABdo/x_XEG0duaZQ/s32/*'/></author><thr:total>0</thr:total></entry><entry><id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-614640065733671379.post-4548548846718831705</id><published>2019-11-27T09:43:00.001-08:00</published><updated>2019-11-27T09:43:38.892-08:00</updated><title type='text'>teste 2</title><content type='html'>sdfsdfsdf</content><link rel='replies' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/feeds/4548548846718831705/comments/default' title='Postar comentários'/><link rel='replies' type='text/html' href='https://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/2019/11/teste-2.html#comment-form' title='0 Comentários'/><link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default/4548548846718831705'/><link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default/4548548846718831705'/><link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/2019/11/teste-2.html' title='teste 2'/><author><name>AngelRibeiro</name><email>noreply@blogger.com</email><gd:image rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail' width='18' height='32' src='//4.bp.blogspot.com/-HCajnihNU-o/Uzoge8-ME2I/AAAAAAAABdo/x_XEG0duaZQ/s32/*'/></author><thr:total>0</thr:total></entry><entry><id>tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-614640065733671379.post-3986601118136760026</id><published>2019-11-27T03:07:00.001-08:00</published><updated>2019-11-27T03:07:02.420-08:00</updated><title type='text'>Teste</title><content type='html'>Teste</content><link rel='replies' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/feeds/3986601118136760026/comments/default' title='Postar comentários'/><link rel='replies' type='text/html' href='https://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/2019/11/teste.html#comment-form' title='0 Comentários'/><link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default/3986601118136760026'/><link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default/3986601118136760026'/><link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://angelribeirocomp.blogspot.com/2019/11/teste.html' title='Teste'/><author><name>AngelRibeiro</name><email>noreply@blogger.com</email><gd:image rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail' width='18' height='32' src='//4.bp.blogspot.com/-HCajnihNU-o/Uzoge8-ME2I/AAAAAAAABdo/x_XEG0duaZQ/s32/*'/></author><thr:total>0</thr:total></entry></feed>
```

So how to I get the Titles and the images the content and the links for the posts?
The code that I'm using is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        myFunction(this);
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default?max-results=3", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('author')[0];
    var y = x.childNodes[0];
    document.getElementById("gd:image").innerHTML =
    y.nodeValue; 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best performance when fetching the data from Blogger feed, I suggest you to use JSON feed instead of XML because it is lightweight and faster.

To get JSON feed, add `alt=json` parameter to your Blogger feed url

```
https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default?alt=json&max-results=3
```

And you can get your posts like the following:

```html
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
function getPosts(json) {
 var list = [];
 var data = json.feed.entry;
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var img = data[i].media$thumbnail ? "<img src='" + data[i].media$thumbnail.$t + "'>" : "";
  list.push("<div><a href='"+ data[i].link.pop().href + "'>" + img + data[i].title.$t + "</a></div>");
 }
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = list.join('');
}
</script>

<script src="https://www.blogger.com/feeds/614640065733671379/posts/default?alt=json&max-results=3&callback=getPosts"></script>
```

Comment: up voted for pointing out that the feed also provides json.  So much easier than converting an xml atom feed.

Comment: Its working just to get the name and the link of the posts but  I need the description too

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no a description key in any type of Blogger feed. you can only get it on blog post page.

Comment: You can also get post content, author, labels and more. Follow the json keys and values and read more about how json works!

Comment: what is that number 614640065733671379 coming from?